# How to use Regular Expression Extractor to get authenticity token with / = + signs?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to correctly parse authenticity token in JMeter which has `+`, `/` and spaces in it and looks like below…

```
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="kJ+AzaV/saCxK+F4Ibh6LeEqH8rpiGZfyRKn3RGX960=" name="csrf-token" />
```

I have a “Regular Expression Extractor” and Regular Expression looks like..
`meta content="([^"]+)" name="csrf-token" />`

The problem is that the `/` gets replaced with `%2F` and `=` at the end gets replace with `%3D` and

```
kJ+AzaV%2FsaCxK+F4Ibh6LeEqH8rpiGZfyRKn3RGX960%3D
```

How can I parse the authenticity token correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your attribute has been *URI encoded*, so you'll need to decode it before attempting to do more

```
window.decodeURIComponent('kJ+AzaV%2FsaCxK+F4Ibh6LeEqH8rpiGZfyRKn3RGX960%3D');
// "kJ+AzaV/saCxK+F4Ibh6LeEqH8rpiGZfyRKn3RGX960="
```

Further, using a *RegExp* to extract data from *HTML* or *XML* is not always the best idea, perhaps you could try parsing it and accessing the *Nodes* and *Attributes* you want via a *DOM Tree*.

Comment: If you don't have access to `window.decodeURIComponent` due to your _Java_ environment, then the `%` means "the next two chars (0-9, a-f) are the byte representing the char we mean", so you'd take them, convert to Byte/Int/Whatever number type (from base 16) and then convert that to Char/String/whatever

Comment: How can I manipulate this? I get the variable in regular Expression, then what element of Jmeter would be used to do this manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing it as a parameter just untick "Encode?" box for it.

If you need to decode this via JavaScript as Paul S. suggests, consider using [__javaScript](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function as follows:

```
${__javaScript(decodeURIComponent("${YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME_HERE}"),)}
```

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series for more details.